# Tesseract configuration for alphanumeric strings: mixes up 2, Z, 6 and G

Tags: java, batch-file, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to configurate tesseract to recognize **alphanumeric strings** of 10 characters long (all uppercase).

This works pretty good, except it seems to mix up the following characters pretty often:

- `2` and `Z`
- `6` and `G`

After some research, I might have found the cause (but I am not sure): there is likely some system in tesseract which makes predictions based on position of characters deferred from dictionaries (or other data). I think Tesseract might choose a `2` over a `Z` because it look a likes but also because it will always occur within a word; a `2` doesn't make much sense in that case. At least that's what I can make of it.

I would like to disable this, so I tried several options without luck:

```
tesseract = new Tesseract();                      
tesseract.setOcrEngineMode(TessAPI.TessOcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);
tesseract.setPageSegMode(7);
tesseract.setTessVariable("load_system_dawg", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("load_freq_dawg", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("load_punc_dawg", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("load_number_dawg", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("load_unambig_dawg", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("load_bigram_dawg", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("load_fixed_length_dawgs", "0");

tesseract.setTessVariable("classify_enable_learning", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("classify_enable_adaptive_matcher", "0");

tesseract.setTessVariable("segment_penalty_garbage", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("segment_penalty_dict_nonword", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("segment_penalty_dict_frequent_word", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("segment_penalty_dict_case_ok", "0");
tesseract.setTessVariable("segment_penalty_dict_case_bad", "0");
```

*Note that this is Java code, but my question is not limited to Java.*

I am not really experienced with Tesseract and seem to find the documentation very unclear. I hope someone else can help me out.

---

To give some more context:

**How do I train Tesseract?**

I train Tesseract by combining over 200 images into one image. Every image contains 10 alphanumeric characters. Also, I am sure the box file is correct.

I build the final language by executing the following batch script:

```
tesseract qwe.combined.jpg qwe.combined.box nobatch box.train

echo combined 1 0 0 0 0 > font_properties

unicharset_extractor qwe.combined.box

shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset qwe.combined.box.tr

mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O qwe.unicharset qwe.combined.box.tr

cntraining qwe.combined.box.tr

copy inttemp qwe.inttemp
copy normproto qwe.normproto
copy pffmtable qwe.pffmtable
copy shapetable qwe.shapetable

combine_tessdata qwe.
```

---

How can I make Tesseract discriminate better between the `2`, `Z`, `6` and `G`?

Comment: Have you had any luck with the problem?